# Laravel is creating cache, but load times are the same

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-7

So I'm attempting to cache a query on one of my controllers, returning roughly 30k records in around 12 - 19 seconds, which is obviously unacceptable.  I'm trying to integrate basic caching, and although I am seeing cached files appear in the project after loading the page, my time to load the results is still the same.  Does anyone have clue why this might be?  I'm relatively new to Laravel – is there somewhere else this caching should be?  I've seen various examples of caching at the route level as well.

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = Cache::remember('questions', 60*60*24, function() {
        return Question::with('tags')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->with('exams.class')
        ->with('assignment.course')
        ->get();
    });

    $archived_questions = Cache::remember('archived-questions', 60*60*24, function() {
        return Question::onlyTrashed()->with('tags')
            ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
    });


    return view('admin.index', ['questions' => $questions, 'archivedQuestions' => $archived_questions]);
}
```

Comment: Just need to check, have you added indexes and foreign keys to these tables? heh

Comment: Yup, checked and they do.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a cache for each index action, meaning every time you load your page you're re-running that query and assigning it to cache

Try this,

```
public function index()
{
    if (Cache::has('questions')) {
        $questions = Cache::get('questions');
    } else {
        $questions = Cache::remember('questions', 60*60*24, function() {
            return Question::with('tags')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->with('exams.class')
            ->with('assignment.course')
            ->get();
        });
    }

    if (Cache::has('archivedQuestions')) {
        $archivedQuestions= Cache::get('archivedQuestions');
    } else {
        $archived_questions = Cache::remember('archived-questions', 60*60*24, function() {
            return Question::onlyTrashed()->with('tags')
                ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
        });
    }
    return view('admin.index', ['questions' => $questions, 'archivedQuestions' => $archived_questions]);
}
```

Look at these docs; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache specifically 'Retrieving Items From The Cache'

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to change things – also question on what you said, doesn't remember() do both checking to see if the cache exists, but also registering that cache if it doesn't exist?

Comment: You're right, maybe I should read the docs lol, can you run `php artisan cache:clear` and let me know if you still get the same issue? also if this does fail. try to copy my code and print inside each 'else' condition to see if it lands there